# Lyapunov method for non-linear autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a system of non - linear autonomous system, let v(x) be a positive definite function about origin. Now , origin is Asymptotically stable then, does it imply that the origin is also stable? I think it is so, as for Asymptotical stability ,there must must exist a Lyapunov function for the non linear autonomous system in an open region around the origin ( which is the necessary condition for origin to be stable) such that derivative of v(x) is positive definite in the region around origin. Please correct me I iam wrong.

Comment: Yes, "asymptotically stable at the origin" means that, as t goes to infinity, x(t) goes to the origin.  "Stable" just means that there exist some neighborhood about the origin such that x(t) never goes outside that neighborhood.  If x is "asymptotically stable about the origin" then  its distance from the origin, has some largest value.  Take the neighborhood to be the disk with that largest value as radius.

Comment: @user247327: No, *stable* means that for *every* neighborhood $U$ there exists a (possibly smaller) neighborhood $V$ such that every solution starting in $V$ remains in $U$ forever. And usually that's also taken as part of the definition of what *asymptotically stable* means.